# Как вызвать функцию Django из шаблона?

Tags: html, python, django

Есть функция `synch` определённая в `views.py`, которая внутри себя обращается к функции `get_companies`, которая в свою очередь делает запрос к API стороннего сервера, и возвращает результат в формате json. Сама `synch` данный результат обрабатывает и методом `update_or_create()` заносит в базу.
Вопрос в следующем:
Как вызвать функцию `synch` из html-шаблона?

Для наглядности прикрепляю uml-схему сего действа.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: аяксом. лучше пост запросом на отдельный урл

Comment: @eri А можно поподробнее, или ссылку на пример? Потому что, пробовал через запросом на отдельный url, но так и не понял, как определить сие чудо в urls.py Делал что-то в духе `path(r'synch', views.synch)` , но на выходе получал 404.